# Android RecyclerView list item doesn't show click animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

As recommended I replaced my ListView by RecyclerView. But now I can't get working the item click animation. Long press animation is working but if I only tap the item I get no tap animation.

I tried different solutions found around here but nothing helped. What is wrong with my code?

The layout that contains the RecyclerView:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/frame_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the list item layout: (I also tried FrameLayout)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Artist"
            android:id="@+id/artist"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code in my activity's onCreate():

```java
recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        // enable swipelayout if scrolled to top
        try {
            int firstPos = mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (firstPos > 0) {
                swipeLayout.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
                if (recyclerview.getScrollState() == 1 && swipeLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    recyclerview.stopScroll();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
});
recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(MainActivity.this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            // do something works
        }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have read through your question, To achieve tap animation you only need to replace the code below found in your list items.

from

```
 android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

to

```
  android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Hope it helps solve your problem